# Xcode 4.2 doesn't show Iphone simulator 3

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, simulator

I have installed the new Xcode 4.2 and added Iphone Simulator 3 and 4 in Xcode-Preferences-Downloads-Components

Create new project and set IOS target SDK - 3.0.

And I don't see an option to build for "iPhone 3 Simulator" and "iPad 3 Simulator", but i see an option to build for "iPhone 4.3 Simulator" and "iPad 4.3 Simulator".

Is there something else I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only Device Debugging Support for iOS 3.x, no simulator.

If you really need to verify compatibility with 3.x you are best off getting a physical device